# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/internal/connector/SupportsStreamingUpdate

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```
query = info_df_fin.selectExpr("to_json(struct(*)) AS value")\
        .writeStream\
        .format("kafka")\
        .option("checkpointLocation", "chkpint_directory")\
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")\
        .option("topic", "Dest_topic")\
        .start()
```

This is the code that I am using to send stream batch data from on kafka topic to another but I am facing an error despite of having all jar file in the location. including "spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.12-2.4.0.jar"

I'm having this error

> 23/09/18 11:15:58 WARN ResolveWriteToStream:
> spark.sql.adaptive.enabled is not supported in streaming
> DataFrames/Datasets and will be disabled. 23/09/18 11:15:58 ERROR
> MicroBatchExecution: Query [id = 23d94359-dabf-41ef-8617-a62859a35adb,
> runId = 57e0c21c-5245-40c5-9878-be1b5b06e106] terminated with error
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> org/apache/spark/sql/internal/connector/SupportsStreamingUpdate   at
> java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)   at
> java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1022)    at
> java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:800)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:698)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:621)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:579)
> at
> java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:527)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider$KafkaTable.newWriteBuilder(KafkaSourceProvider.scala:397)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2Writes$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$v2$V2Writes$$newWriteBuilder(V2Writes.scala:144)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2Writes$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(V2Writes.scala:90)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2Writes$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(V2Writes.scala:43)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.$anonfun$transformDownWithPruning$1(TreeNode.scala:512)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:104)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode.transformDownWithPruning(TreeNode.scala:512)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$plans$logical$AnalysisHelper$$super$transformDownWithPruning(LogicalPlan.scala:31)

I am trying to send the streamed data from one kafka topic to another

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62921366/noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-spark-sql-internal-connector-simpletableprovide  Could be a version mismatch between the spark version used in compiled jar and spark version in deployed environment.

Comment: Removed Kafka tag since error is related to internal SparkSQL class. Please do make sure both the jar versions match your running Spark and Scala environment

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely using a different version of spark.

If your kafka jar file is spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.12-2.4.0.jar, you should be having spark 2.4 with Scala 2.12

Alternatively, use one of the latest stable versions of Spark like 3.3 and update the jar file name to spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.12-3.3.0.jar